Finding all keys that have a matching library item in excel
I would like a way to tell our manufacturing floor which assemblies share components with other assemblies by comparing their bills of materials.  Ideally this would be something where I could give the assembly number and get back a list like you can get with index(aggregate(15,3)...) of all the other assemblies that share parts.  The image below is a mockup of what I'm hoping to achieve....anyone have any ideas?  (im on 365 but ideally this could work on office 2013 as thats the newest version I can guarantee all users will be working with)


Office 365 solution, taking three inputs, it calculates your required output:
=LET(
    lookup,D2,
    assy,A2:A23,
    mats,B2:B23,
    filter, FILTER(mats, assy=lookup),
    sharedAssemblies, UNIQUE(FILTER(assy, (ISNUMBER(MATCH(mats, filter, 0))) * (assy<>lookup))),
    sharedCounts, BYROW(sharedAssemblies, LAMBDA(assembly, SUM((assy=assembly) * ISNUMBER(MATCH(mats, filter, 0))))),
    HSTACK(sharedAssemblies, sharedCounts)
)


Certainly! This Excel formula leverages the LET function to streamline calculations and perform various operations step by step. Here's the explanation for each line:

=LET(lookup,D2,


Define a variable named lookup and set its value to the cell D2.


assy,A2:A23,


Define a variable named assy and assign it the range A2:A23


mats,B2:B23,


Define a variable named mats and assign it the range B2:B23.


filter, FILTER(mats, assy=lookup),


Define a variable named filter that extracts materials (mats) where the assembly (assy) matches the lookup value.


sharedAssemblies, UNIQUE(FILTER(assy, (ISNUMBER(MATCH(mats, filter, 0))) * (assy<>lookup))),


Define sharedAssemblies as the list of unique assemblies that share materials with the lookup assembly, excluding the lookup


sharedCounts, BYROW(sharedAssemblies, LAMBDA(assembly, SUM((assy=assembly) * ISNUMBER(MATCH(mats, filter, 0))))),


Define sharedCounts as the count of shared materials for each assembly in sharedAssemblies.

BYROW: Applies the subsequent LAMBDA function row by row on sharedAssemblies.
LAMBDA(assembly, ...): A custom function to calculate the count for a single assembly.

(assy=assembly): Identifies rows where the assembly matches the current assembly.
ISNUMBER(MATCH(mats, filter, 0)): Identifies rows where the material is shared with the lookup assembly.
SUM(...): Counts the rows where both conditions are TRUE (shared material and matching assembly).






HSTACK(sharedAssemblies, sharedCounts)


Combine sharedAssemblies and sharedCounts horizontally into a single array with two columns.
Logic: The HSTACK function places sharedAssemblies in the first column and sharedCounts in the second column.


Thank you, that's exactly what I asked for but I've not used some of these functions before.  I think I'm beginning to see how this works but how could I alter this to add a layer?    so, for example, if I then had a list of jobs making different assemblies, would there be a way to compare the list of assemblies to my list of jobs that make them to return a list of the jobs that make any of the assemblies with matching materials?

@KyleCranfill - it's doable but it's a new question isn't it?

thats fair.  I'll mark this as answered and add a new question. @Michal

Could you help me to understand better what this part is doing?  LAMBDA(assembly, SUM((assy=assembly) * ISNUMBER(MATCH(mats, filter, 0)      I think I understand the rest of the formula here but I'm still confused on how this section is functioning.

@KyleCranfill - please see the ammended answer.
